# how to know the absloute path of images/js used in another website through my webapplication

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

for  translating the website i am loading the website  through htmlaglity pack . i want to know the absolute path of /js/image/css  referenced in website.
 like when i do view source and click on(../Styles/superfish.css) it give me the complete path of the file (https://URL NAMe/Site/Styles/superfish.css) 
but i want  this  complete path  programmaticaly  in my web application.

source code:

```
    public ActionResult TransURL(string surl)
{
html = web.Load(surl);
//taking all the script tag 
 var nodesScript = (from ele in root.Descendants("script")

                               select ele);
            foreach (var e in nodesScript)
            {

                string value = e.GetAttributeValue("src", "not found");
                   //here value is ../Styles/superfish.css 
                Uri ur = new Uri(surl);
                    //
                       Uri ur1=  new Uri(ur, Url.Content(value));
        }
            }
```

Comment: show some of your code work to us.

Comment: I hope you are not allowed to gain knowledge abut absolute paths on the server!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you to achieve your requirement.

```
<link type="text/css" src="@Url.Content("../Styles/superfish.css")" />
```

Comment: i have uploaed the code ,url.content is not giving the complete path